# Please could you explain to me how currying works when it comes to higher order functions, particularly the example below

Tags: function, haskell, currying

Can someone please help me with the below,

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

I do not understand how the above works. If we had something like `(+3) 10` surely it would produce `13`? How is that `f (f x)`. Basically I do not understand currying when it comes to looking at higher order functions.

So what I'm not understanding is if say we had a function of the form `a -> a -> a` it would take an input `a` then produce a function which expects another input a to produce an output. So if we had `add 5 3` then doing `add 5` would produce a function which would expect the input `3` to produce a final output of `8`. My question is how does that work here. We take a function in as an input so does partial function application work here like it did in `add x y` or am I completely overcomplicating everything?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of help you need. The above function works by taking a function `f` and a value `x` and returning `f(f(x))` (or `f (f x)` in Haskell notation).

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're not understanding here. Fill out the example, what does `applyTwice (+3) 10` evaluate to?

Comment: Do you understand the example better if you ignore the word "currying"?

Comment: So what I'm not understanding is if say we had a function of the form a -> a -> a it would take an input a then produce a function which expects another input a to produce an output. So if we had add 5 3 then doing add 5 would produce a function which would expect the input 3 to produce a final output of 8. My question is how does that work here. We take a function in as an input so does partial function application work here like it did in add x y or am I completely overcomplicating everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not currying, that's partial application.

```
> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

> :t (+) 3
(+) 3 :: Num a =>    a -> a
```

The partial application `(+) 3` indeed produces a function `(+3)`<sup>(*)</sup> which awaits another numerical input to produce its result. And it does so, whether once or *twice*.

You example is expanded as

```
applyTwice (+3) 10 = (+3) ((+3) 10) 
                   = (+3) (10+3)
                   =      (10+3)+3
```

That's all there is to it.

---

<sup>(*)</sup>(actually, it's `(3 +)`, but that's the same as `(+ 3)` anyway).

---

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) clarifies in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709768/please-could-you-explain-to-me-how-currying-works-when-it-comes-to-higher-order/69710245?noredirect=1#comment123241734_69710245) (quoted with  minimal copy editing),

> partial application is an illusion created by the fact that functions only take one argument, and the combination of the right associativity of `(->)` and the left associativity of function application. `(+) 3` isn't really a *partial* application. It's just [a regular] application of `(+)` to an argument `3`.

So seen from the point of view of other, more traditional languages, we refer to this as a distinction between currying and partial application.

But seen from the Haskell perspective it is all indeed about currying, i.e. applying a function to its arguments one at a time, until fully saturated as indicated by its type (i.e. `a->a->a` value applied to an `a` value becomes an `a->a` value, and that then becomes an `a` value when applied to an `a` value in its turn).

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, I really was thinking about this the wrong way. This has been great help and really cleared a lot up. Thank you so much!

Comment: To be fair, partial application is an illusion created by the fact that functions only take one argument and the combination of the right associativity of `(->)` and the left associativity of function application. `(+) 3` isn't *really* a partial application. It's just the application of `(+)` to an argument `3`.

Comment: @chepner correct on all counts, :) but, it was once said, best explanation is necessarily wrong.  I'm paraphrasing; so it's actually I that have just invented this. :)

Comment: @chepner what that means though, is that we must talk in the language of the asker, for them to understand the answer better / easier. so, in their language, there is indeed this distinction, and that's exactly where their misunderstanding was. evidently. :) but you raise important points; perhaps I'll add your comment into the answer, with attribution of course.

Comment: @chepner I've edited, thanks. (I guess I was thinking about `curry`ing instead, when writing the answer!)